# Knockout - load data into model with Ajax - not straight away

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

Here's a simplified example of my knockout model.  The problem I'm having is that as soon as the page loads, the quiz is loaded.  Why does it get run straight away and how can I stop it so that it only get's run when I want, say, on the click of a button?

Do I even need to use `subscribe` to do this?

HTML:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: quizCount(quizCount() + 1)">
    Click Me
</button>
<hr />
<div data-bind="visible: !loaded()">No Quiz</div>
<div data-bind="visible: loaded">Quiz Loaded!</div>
<hr />
<h3>Debug</h3>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(quizModel)"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quizModel = { };

    // DOM ready.
    $(function () {
        function QuizViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.loaded = ko.observable(false);
            self.questions = ko.observable();
            self.quizCount = ko.observable();
        };

        quizModel = new QuizViewModel();

        quizModel.quizCount.subscribe(function (newCount) {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetNew", "api/quiz")', function (data) {
                quizModel.questions(data.Questions);
            }).complete(function () {
                quizModel.loaded(true);
            });
        });

        ko.applyBindings(quizModel);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe is only used for listening to changes in an observable so it will run immediately as soon as the observable gets a value.

You need to add this function to your viewmodel as a method, likely to be called getQuestions:

```
function QuizViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.loaded = ko.observable(false);
    self.questions = ko.observable();
    self.quizCount = ko.observable();
    self.getQuestions = function(){
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetNew", "api/quiz")', function (data) {
            self.questions(data.Questions);
        }).complete(function () {
            self.loaded(true);
        });
    }
};
```

then you can easily have a button or something that binds to this method on click:

```
<button data-bind="click: getQuestions">Get questions</button>
```